# С помощью метода filter() вернуть индекс максимального значения

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [1, 5, 6, 9, 7];

var arr2 = arr.filter(function(element, index){
   ...
   return index;
});
```

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) возвращает новый массив, а не индекс. А функция, вызываемая для каждого элемента, возвращает true, если элемент исходного массива должен попасть в результат и false, если не должен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.filter` для этого не предназначен.

А `Array.reduce` - подойдет.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

```js
var arr1 = [1, 5, 6, 9, 7];

var index = arr1.reduce(function(result, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
  return (currentValue > arr[result])? currentIndex : result;
}, 0);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: Это понятно, но мне надо именно с filter()

Comment: @YURII не темните :), зачем Вам нужно отверткой забить гвоздь?

Comment: я не темню))) мне такое условие задачи поставили )) я обязан так сделать ))

Comment: @YURII скажите ему в лицо о том какой он неумный. а, возможно, это тест и вам нужно об этом (что фильтром не решается подобная задача) сказать в лицо в любом случае

Comment: @YURII такая постановка задачи заставляет усомниться в душевном здоровье постановщика

Comment: @YURII, это проверка...  не водись...  поверь, в данном случае сделаешь так как в задаче (костылем), если получится,  провалишь  экзамен...

Comment: @Igor А вы могли бы мне объяснить как работает данный код, а то я не могу разобраться. Я был бы очень признателен!

Comment: @Air - "это проверка... не водись..." - никогда еще советский разведчик не был так близок к провалу

Comment: @Igor,  это точно... ))) Вроде не вОдись, а не вЕдись...

Answer (score 3):

Как правильно написано в соседнем ответе

> Array.filter для этого не предназначен.

Поэтому просто еще один вариант без него.

```js
let arr = [1, 5, 6, 9, 7];
let index = arr.indexOf(Math.max(...arr));
console.log(index);
```

Comment: так, почему не использован `filter`?

Comment: о-о-о, поздравляю с 30к!

Comment: @Igor благодарю. день держалось 30.000 ровненько)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а если будет массив объектов, и надо искать по определенному свойству, сработает ?

Comment: @YURII что именно? фильтр или код выше?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский код выше

Comment: @YURII нет конечно. вы же видите только метод `max`, который находит максимальное число в массиве, и `indexOf`.... видно что тут не может быть никаких обращений к полям...... разве что заворачивать в еще один цикл......хотя это будет лишне, потому что в таком случае можно будет воспользоваться просто  `findIndex` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)